# Restrict user's access from different ip in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to block users from accessing sugarcrm from their home. They can only access it from our office's computer. How to do this ? I am using sugarondemand as host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this module on your staging instance : http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/irm/ or asking to the support if they can validate this module for your instance

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SugarOnDemand then just put in a case and ask support to help you with this.  There is really nothing you can do from the outside on this, it has to be done on their servers.